# Need to change plugin and functions.php from $_SESSION to Cookie

Tags: wordpress, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using a plugin which uses PHPSESSID to remember a vehicle selector - this has been excluded from cache at WPEngine as they specifically ignore PHPSESSID. If a user is inactive on the site for 24 minutes (I think) or closes the browser window, the selected vehicle gets forgotten. I would like to change the amount of time before the vehicle gets forgotten to 24 hours, or a week. Creating php.ini and adding ONLY `session.gc_maxlifetime=86400` appears to make no difference.

I'm using WP 5.0.3, WooCommerce and hosted at WPEngine.

I'm considering modifying the plugin to use cookies instead - presumably this would allow me to set an expire time. Do I simply find all `$_SESSION['vpf']` references in the plugin files and replace with `$_COOKIE['vpf']`? I also have some customisation done in my functions.php file. Again, do I just change from SESSION to COOKIE?

Thank you

Comment: You could also store a "valid until date" field in your session. Then when you fetch it from the session, you can check if the date is expired. Something like this: `$_SESSION['vehcle'] = json_encode(['vehicle_selector' => 'someVehicle', 'valid_until' => '2019-01-20T12:31:56+0000']); $data = json_decode($_SESSION['vehicle'], true); $validUntilDateTime = new \DateTime($data['valid_until']); $expired = new \DateTime() > $validUntilDateTime`